# How to add padding to glTexture?

Tags: opengl

I want to add a 1 pixel padding to all sides of my glTexture on its creation without modifying my source buffer. Are there any commands to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the target texture object using glTexImage2D (or glTexStorage2D) with the destination size, and using a null pointer for the data argument. Then use glTexSubImage2D to upload the image into the desired rectangle.

Comment: Note that doing this will mean that the edge pixels have undefined values.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Indeed, but OP just asked for padding, but did not mention it had to be a specific value.